# JQuery: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

У меня есть следующий код:

```
$('input[name="switch-tab"]').on('change', function () {
        $.get("/workspace/devicetype", function (type) {
            updateState($(this).val(), type);
        });

        if ($(this).val() === 'tab-1') {
            // тут я меняю классы на элементах 
        }
        if ($(this).val() === 'tab-2') {
            // тут я меняю классы на элементах 

        }
        if ($(this).val() === 'tab-3') {
            // тут я меняю классы на элементах 
        }
        if ($(this).val() === 'tab-4') {
            //  тут я меняю классы на элементах 
        }
    });

function updateState(newState, type) {
        $.post("/workspace/ToTabView", {
            state: newState,
            device: type
        }, function (result) {
            $("#_current_tab").empty();
            $("#_current_tab").append(result);
        });
    }
```

но при выполнении `function updateState(newState, type)` я получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
>       at n.fn.init.val (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at Object.success (main.js:52)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at y (jquery.min.js:4)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:4)

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контекст, с которым вызывается анонимная функция, передаваемая в `$.get`, не тот.

```
    $.get("/workspace/devicetype", (function (type) {
        updateState($(this).val(), type);
    }).bind(this));
```

или

```
    $.get("/workspace/devicetype", type =>
        updateState($(this).val(), type)
    );
```

или

```
    var self = this;
    $.get("/workspace/devicetype", function (type) {
        updateState($(self).val(), type);
    });
```